# web page is utf and the text inside is in russian, when I grab the webpage with python it does not show correctly

Tags: python, python-requests, lxml

```
base_url = "http://vesti.az"
link = "http://vesti.az"
#these two lines identifies character encoding
enc = urllib.request.urlopen(link).read()
print(chardet.detect(enc))
#end of charset identifier
page = requests.get(link)
print(page.encoding)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)    
links = tree.xpath('//div[@class="news-list"]/ul/li/a/@href') #here I get the last added news link
new_link = base_url + links[0]
if show_details == 1:
    print(new_link)


info = requests.get(new_link)
agac = html.fromstring(info.content) #here I open last news link
newsTitle = agac.xpath('//title/text()') #here I get the news title
newsTitle = u''.join(newsTitle)

b0 = agac.xpath('//article[@class="article-content js-mediator-article"]//text()')
b0 = u"".join(b0)
b0 = b0.strip()

newsBody = b0 #re.sub("Oxunub:.*", "", b0, flags=re.DOTALL)

if show_details == 1:
    print(new_link)
    print(newsTitle) #here I print the news title
    print(newsBody)
```

And, unfortunately when I print the news title I get something like this: ÐÐ·ÐµÑÐ±Ð°Ð¹Ð´Ð¶Ð°Ð½ÐµÑ Ð¿Ð¾Ð»ÑÑÐ¸Ð» ÑÑÐ¶ÐµÐ»Ð¾Ðµ ÑÐ°Ð½ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ðµ Ð²Ð¾ Ð²ÑÐµÐ¼Ñ Ð½Ð°Ð¿Ð°Ð´ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ñ Ð½Ð° ÑÐ¿ÑÐ°Ð²Ð»ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ðµ Ð¤Ð¡Ð   | Vesti.az | ÐÐ»Ð°Ð²Ð½ÑÐµ Ð½Ð¾Ð²Ð¾ÑÑÐ¸ ÐÐ·ÐµÑÐ±Ð°Ð¹Ð´Ð¶Ð°Ð½Ð° | ÐÐ¾Ð²Ð¾ÑÑÐ¸ ÐÐ·ÐµÑÐ±Ð°Ð¹Ð´Ð¶Ð°Ð½Ð°

Which is definitely something that I am not looking for. I have tried to change python file encoding, I did not succeed. Is there a way to solve that problem?

I used hash(#) and explained what I am doing in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The KEY to getting the UTF-8 representation of a binary string is:

> **info.content.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')**

That's it. The code below uses it:

```
import urllib.request
import chardet
import requests
from lxml import html

show_details = 1
base_url = "http://vesti.az"
link = "http://vesti.az"
#these two lines identifies character encoding
enc = urllib.request.urlopen(link).read()
print(chardet.detect(enc))
#end of charset identifier
page = requests.get(link)
print(page.encoding)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)    
links = tree.xpath('//div[@class="news-list"]/ul/li/a/@href') #here I get the last added news link
new_link = base_url + links[0]
if show_details == 1:
    print(new_link)
info = requests.get(new_link)
# print(info.content.decode('utf-8', 'ignore'))
# print(info.content)
agac = html.fromstring(info.content.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')) #here I open last news link
newsTitle = agac.xpath('//title/text()') #here I get the news title
newsTitle = u''.join(newsTitle)

b0 = agac.xpath('//article[@class="article-content js-mediator-article"]//text()')
b0 = u"".join(b0)
b0 = b0.strip()

newsBody = b0 #re.sub("Oxunub:.*", "", b0, flags=re.DOTALL)

if show_details == 1:
    # print(new_link)
    print(newsTitle) #here I print the news title
    # print(newsBody)
```

and the output is:

```
>python3.6 -u "russian_Cg.py"
{'encoding': 'utf-8', 'confidence': 0.99, 'language': ''}
utf-8
http://vesti.az/news/329186
ВС Армении продолжают нарушать режим прекращения огня | Vesti.az | Главные новости Азербайджана | Новости Азербайджана
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I closely examined the changes, and got it. Thanks a lot!